# Getting same data repeatedly more than multiple times(in thousands)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get data in table format from database with multiple queries. I am getting the exact data but the data am getting is same data repeatedly more than thousand times. Please I need a help to fix this to get actual data not multiple data below is my code. Please have a look at it. I am not getting any error but the data am getting is multiple and repeated data.

```
 controller:
public function getReports()
    {
    $records = [];
        $data = [];
        $data['title']         = 'test Report'; 
        $date_type             = $this->input->get('filter_options');
        $course            = $this->input->get('course');
        $filter_options    = $date_type;
        $department        = $this->input->get('department');
        $division          = $this->input->get('division');
        $month                 = 1;
        $year              = date('Y');
        $day               = date('d');
        $data['department'] = $department;
        $data['course'] = $course;
        $data['division'] = $division;
        $data['date_type'] = $date_type;

$course_condition = ' AND 1=1 ';
if($course)
    $course_condition = ' AND o.title="'.$course.'"';

$department_condition = ' AND 1=1 ';
if($department)
    $department_condition = ' AND u.department="'.$department.'"';


$date_condition = ' and 1=1 ';
        if($date_type==1)
        {

            $date_condition = ' and ta.submittimestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 300 DAY) AND NOW() ';
                 //dd($date_condition);
        }
        else if($date_type==2)
        {
            $date_condition = ' and MONTH(ta.submittimestamp) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND YEAR(ta.submittimestamp) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) ';  

        }
        else if($date_type==3)
        {
            $year = $this->input->get('year');
            $month = $this->input->get('month');


            $date_condition = '  and YEAR(ta.submittimestamp) = "'.$year.'" and MONTH(ta.submittimestamp) = "'.$month.'" ';  


        }


$group_condition = "GROUP by u.usr_id";

if ($course) 

    $users_query="SELECT o.title as course_title,u.*,u.usr_id,o.obj_id FROM object_data o,usr_data u,obj_members rn WHERE o.obj_id=rn.obj_id AND u.usr_id=rn.usr_id AND o.type='crs'  AND o.obj_id=$course";



$user_records = $this->base_model->executeSelectQuery($users_query);

$final_data = [];

foreach($user_records as $user)
{
    if(!$course)
        continue;
$user_course_query="SELECT *, (select obj_id FROM object_reference f WHERE e.child = f.ref_id limit 1 ) as final_reference FROM object_data a , object_data g,tree c,tree e , object_reference b ,object_reference f,object_reference d WHERE a.obj_id = b.obj_id AND b.ref_id = c.parent AND c.child = d.ref_id AND d.ref_id = e.parent AND f.obj_id = g.obj_id AND a.obj_id=$course ";

        $user_course_records = $this->base_model->executeSelectQuery($user_course_query);

    foreach($user_course_records as $course_data)
    { 
        $final_reference=$course_data->final_reference;
        $user_tests_query = "SELECT u.firstname,o.*,ta.*,tpr.workingtime,tcr.mark_official,(tcr.reached_points/tcr.max_points)*100 as result FROM usr_data u,object_data o,tst_active ta,tst_tests tt ,tst_pass_result tpr, tst_result_cache tcr WHERE u.usr_id=ta.user_fi AND tt.obj_fi=o.obj_id AND ta.test_fi=tt.test_id  AND ta.active_id=tpr.active_fi AND tcr.active_fi=ta.active_id      AND u.usr_id=$user->usr_id AND  o.obj_id = $final_reference ".$date_condition;


    $user_tests = $this->base_model->executeSelectQuery($user_tests_query);

        foreach($user_tests as $test)
        {

            $dta['usr_id']         = $user->usr_id;
            $dta['firstname']      = $user->firstname;
            $dta['email']          = $user->email;
            $dta['matriculation']  = $user->matriculation;
            $dta['approve_date']   = $user->approve_date;
            $dta['department']     = $user->department;
            $dta['tries']          = $test->tries;
            $dta['test_title']     = $test->title;
            $dta['submittimestamp']    = $test->submittimestamp;
            $dta['workingtime']    = $test->workingtime;
           // $dta['mark_official']    = $test->mark_official;
           $dta['result']  = $test->result;
        if($test->mark_official=='passed')
            $result_status = '<span class="label label-primary"> Passed </span>';
        else if($test->mark_official=='failed')
            $result_status = '<span class="label label-danger"> Failed </span>';
                $dta['status'] = $result_status;
            $dta['division'] = $this->udfTextData(2);
            $dta['job_title'] = $this->udfTextData(6);
            $final_data[] = $dta;
        }
    }

}
$data['records'] = $final_data;
```

Comment: Looks like you are wide open for SQL injection attacks.. Use codeigniter's `$this->db->escape()` function to protect against SQL injections.

Comment: where can i use it?

Comment: everywhere there is a unsafe SQL parameter.. `o.title="'.$course.'"` for example to make it safe `o.title="'.$this->db->escape($course).'"`

Comment: how can i use it can u please tell me .. am aware of it

Comment: okay i understand but for queries how can i use it?

Comment: first of all post your db structure with some sample data - what you are doing here looks insane, and second instead of claiming you get your data multiple times - you should explain what exactly you want